# fb login button has to be hit twice

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

Is there a way to make the login so that the users don't have to click the login button twice? When they click on the login it goes back to the index (my redirect uri) but doesn't login. They have to click the button again to login.

I have the login script inside the if ( isset( $session ) ) statement.

```
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication(APPNUMBER, APPSECRET);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('MY_URL');
$permissions = array(
    'email',
    'user_birthday',
    'user_location'
);

try {
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['access_token'] ) ) {
        // Check if an access token has already been set.
        $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['access_token'] );
    } else {
        // Get access token from the code parameter in the URL.
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    }

    if ( isset( $session ) ) {
        // Retrieve & store the access token in a session.
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $session->getToken();
        // Log in code here
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can see the full code here if you need to: http://pastebin.com/1d5tDAXU

Comment: What do you mean by clicking login twice? Do you have screenshots to depict the behavior?